# Laravel 5.5 Trait not found

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I can't wrap my head around this, as I have this on another project and works just fine.
It is currently giving me this error

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
>   Trait 'App\Traits\ResponseTrait' not found

The UserRepository works just fine, the trait does not. I've tried renaming the trait, moving it to the repository folder, chmod it to 777, and I have no idea what could be wrong.

Meet my HomeController, the laravel's default:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository as User;
use App\Traits\ResponseTrait;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
  use ResponseTrait;

  private $user;

  /**
  * Create a new controller instance.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function __construct(User $user)
  {
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }

  /**
  * Show the application dashboard.
  *
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
  public function index()
  {
    //dd($this->user->all()->toArray());
    //You can ignore the self:: part, as it doesn't reach this far.
    self::setData($this->user->all()->toArray());
    return "test";
    return view('home');
  }
}
```

The trait:

```
<?

namespace App\Traits;

trait ResponseTrait {
  public function setData($array) {

  }
}
```

The trait's path is /app/Traits/ResponseTrait.php

At my composer.json, I've got PSR-4 autoload with the App directive.

```
"psr-4": {
   "App\\": "app/"
}
```

Edit1: I have tried composer dump-autoload, issue remains

Comment: try composer dump-autoload

Comment: @Sohel0415 tried that, remains the same

Comment: if you have a remote server and you work locally try to don't forget to upload your code. Sometime happens.

Comment: Do you have the php code delimiters / tags in ResponseTrait.php? Looking at your code, I don't think there are.

Comment: @Edwin I do and was the first thing that I validated, it is on the remote server

Comment: is your filename and trait name same??

Comment: @Sohel0415 he posted that in the question

Comment: Don't use `<?`, always use `<?php`.

Comment: Yes, I try to use the same names in order to be more organized @Sohel0415.  There is a delimiter on Trait, I forgot to place it, just edited

Comment: Gonna commit senppuku as I missed the php, thanks everyone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `<?`, always use `<?php`.

Short open tags need to be enabled in php.ini and are not widely supported because they conflict with other languages.

Comment: Can't believe I've completely missed the php part, thanks for pointing it out. Problem solved